# Bash how to combine parameters

Tags: linux, bash

I have made a script with around 10 optional paramaters that I can give with it:

```
-s sorts the list
-d gives all the directories of the map
-a also the hidden files of the map
```

Example: `. MyScript -d Downloads`

But now I would like a proper way to combine all my paramaters

So I could do: `-sda or -s -d`

Is their an easy way to let this work?
If anyone has a litle explanation or tutorial about this please post it!

Thnx for reading

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getopts` internal [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function. Try like this example:

```
while getopts abc: name; do
  echo $name, OPTARG: $OPTARG, OPTIND: $OPTIND, OPTERR: $OPTERR
done
```

Run: `./test -ab -c file`

Result:

```
a, OPTARG: , OPTIND: 1, OPTERR: 1
b, OPTARG: , OPTIND: 2, OPTERR: 1
c, OPTARG: file, OPTIND: 4, OPTERR: 1
```

The variable `name` will be set to the parsed argument. If there is a `:` after the character then an argument is expected which is placed to `OPTARG` variable. `OPTIND` show the next argument to be processed.

If `OPTERR` is set then [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) displays an error message if error occurred. If the first arg is `:` then error messages are suppressed.

Run: `./test -d`

Result:

```
./test: illegal option -- d
?, OPTARG: , OPTIND: 2, OPTERR: 1
```

or `./test -c` (`-c` need an extra argument)

Result:

```
./test: option requires an argument -- c
?, OPTARG: , OPTIND: 2, OPTERR: 1
```

So You can test if `name` is `?` then it is a bad option.

Answer (score 2):

I think `getopts` is what you're looking for.
[Here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) a simple tutorial to get you started.

An example (taken directly from tutorial):

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Regards

Comment: This works but if I would put ":ab:" and for a) echo "My name is.. b) echo My age is... and if you do -ab than it has to say another sentence how should I need to set that?

Comment: @user2252399 `getopts` does only support one character options, and it is builtin bash. If you want you may take a look at `getopt`, which is an external tool (not builtin) and it can handle multi-character parameters with double dash prefix. Here the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/getopt/)

Comment: @user2252399 With :ab: the b option needs an argument. You can call it with '-ab foo' and have both case labels executed--the while iterates over all options.